# Динамический массив с произвольным количеством измерений

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Помогите разобраться с созданием массива:
задача в том, чтобы динамически построить массив с произвольным количеством измерений и их произвольной глубиной.
На вход поступает одномерный массив `int ndims[]` с произвольным (`n`) количеством элементов, где i-ый элемент определяет глубину i-го измерения целевого массива, а количество его измерений, соответственно, равно `n`.
Алгоритм мне вроде и понятен: создаем массив глубиной `ndims[0]` с указателями, затем создаем `ndims[0]` количество массивов глубиной `ndims[1]` и присваиваем их адреса элементам первого массива, и так далее для каждого из созданных (можно оформить рекуррентно). На бэйсике я бы это написал, так как там любой "указатель" - это банально `integer`, содержащий адрес в памяти, нет никаких проблем с присваиванием и преобразованием. 
Но у меня маленький опыт писания на C++, я не слишком хорошо владею этим языком и абсолютно не понимаю, как реализовать это всё на нем. Хотелось бы получить вашу помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Посмотри в сети тему "Стандартная библиотека шаблонов - STL". Конечно же, данную задачу можно реализовать простой командой new-delete, но лучше "покопай" в сторону шаблонов.

Comment: Конечные массивы должны содержать элементы какого типа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно представить массив в виде дерева. Динамический массив динамических массивов динамических массивов и т.д..

```
template<typename T> struct MultiArray
{
    MultiArray(const T& val=T()): Value(val) {};
    MultiArray& operator[](uintp index) {return SubArrays[index];}
    void Add(const T& val) {SubArrays.push_back(val);}
    operator T&() {return Value;}
    vector<MultiArray> SubArrays;
    T Value;
};
```

Конечно, этот способ не самый лучший, так приходится хранить много лишнего. К тому же он не для новичков в C++. Это первое что пришло в голову.

Надеюсь, разберёшься, как построить такой массив по массиву измерений?

Comment: Для N-мерного массива размера S: 

1 + S * (1 + S * (...)) = 1 + S + S^2 + ... = Sum from i=1 to N { S^(i-1) } 

Размер излишков примерно S^(N-1), в то время как размер массива растёт как S^N, что означает 1/S-ая часть коллекции всегда будет пустовать.

Comment: Да, а ещё будут излишки от vector'а, который в пустом занимает примерно 12-16 байт(в зависимости от реализации).

Comment: смысл понятен, я ещё не работал с контейнерами и пока не понимаю, что физически из себя представляет вектор, но буду разбираться, большое спасибо

Answer (score 3):

В стиле Си видится следующая реализация. Если не ошибаюсь, то общее количество элементов total получается

```
for (total = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++)
    total = total * ndims[i];
```

Допустим, память занимаемая одним элементом elsize байт (Например для double elsize = sizeof(double)). Выделим память под все элементы массива

```
double *ndimarr = malloc(total*elsize) // адрес первого элемента (все индексы 0)
```

Далее для обращения к i,j,k... элементу вычислите его номер nelem (от начала). Указатель на этот элемент (его адрес) - ndimarr+nelem.

Далее, надеюсь понятно.

Comment: да, понятно, большое спасибо
на хэшкоде почему-то нельзя пометить более одного ответа правильными(

Comment: Это не страшно, главное что бы Вам помогло в решении задачи.